# InnoDB, когда можно без foreignkey?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

В каких ситуациях, можно пренебрегать foreignkey?

Хочу сделать для себя базу данных для хранения блокчейнов: монет, litecoin, bitcoin, dogecoin.

Да бы шарить по tx и номерам кошельков. В какой то момент сложилась ситуация, что я не могу увеличивать ssd хранилище и я решил разбить на 3 базы данных, на разных серверах, первая база данных, хранит все tx начинающиеся от "a" до "p", вторая "q" до "9". Все переводы связанные с tx, хранятся там же. В третьей бд,  находится список всех кошельков + баланс. И информация о блоках.  Шарю я по tx и номерам кошельков, как было сказано выше. Между списком кошельков, транзакциями, tx и блоками, имеются связи через id в виде внешних ключей, при разделении на 3 разных сервера, по сути эти внешние ключи будут не возможными. Можно ли ими пренебречь, как это может сказаться? И какие решение в данной ситуации можете подсказать вы?

Comment: `foreignkey` существует для обеспечения целостности данных. Если вас устраивает факт, что состояние ваших БД может быть не консистентным, то вам не нужны внешние ключи.

Comment: Пренебрегать никакими ключами нельзя. Все ключи должны быть созданы и включены. Это позволит в будущем избежать несогласованности данных.

Comment: Если есть гарантия, что приложение своей логикой само обеспечит целостность данных, то можете не включать внешние ключи. Другими словами, ответственность за целостность данных полностью лежит на вас.